# Objective-c Attaching multiple PDF's to email

Tags: ios, pdf, zip, email-attachments

I have an app for our field sales team that generates customer data based on some inputs. The sales rep can then email that data as an attached PDF doc (created programmatically in the app). I also have a stored PDF document with some marketing information on our products that also gets attached to the email. This PDF was created in Apple's Pages and imported into the bundle and then is moved to the docs directory.

My problem is when I attach the programmatically created PDF, the app functions fine. When I attach the stored PDF file, in the email on the iPad both attachments have the .pdf extension but when I receive them in my email (Lotus Notes - I know, I know : (  ) both files come with .pdf.zip extensions and cannot be opened.

If I send just the stored one, the same, .pdf.zip.

On my desktop I can open the original file and read it in Preview and Adobe Reader so it doesn't seem corrupted. Any ideas as to what is going on here?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is actually zipping the files, I think it is putting the .zip extension on in error. I tested it with my gmail account and it worked fine so I am thinking this is a Lotus issue, unfortunately that's the companies email app so I'll need to figure something out.

Comment: Send one file to your gmail account (or use an old one). Open the message using "source view" and grab the MIME info which will be between your text message and the start of the PDF - include at least a line or two of the PDF message. Then update this question with that info. Also, from gmail, send your lotus address a pdf. If that gets through OK, then copy THAT message's MIME info too - so we can compare. In the end you may need to attach the data to the email as text with a specially crafted MIME header.